# How can I iterate over the results of an API call using react?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a search form. The user can search on company name, first and last name. I submit the search parameters to an API:

https:/hiddenlink.cfc?method=getSearch&companyname=${this.state.companyName}&firstname=${this.state.firstName}&lastname=${this.state.lastName}`
      )

I can see that the data is being returned:

[image]

Here is my `onSubmit` function:

```
handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const response = await axios.get(`linkhidden.cfc?method=getSearch&companyname=${this.state.companyName}&firstname=${this.state.firstName}&lastname=${this.state.lastName}`)
    .then(result => {
        this.setState({ phonebook: result.phonebook });
        console.log(result);
    });
};
```

How do I update the state with the data returned from the API and display the results?

I have googled for 3 days and tried everything and nothing works :(

Comment: How are you calling the API? Can you show that part of the code?

Comment: <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

Comment: handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await axios
      .get(
        `linkhidden.cfc?method=getSearch&companyname=${this.state.companyName}&firstname=${this.state.firstName}&lastname=${this.state.lastName}`
      )
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          phonebook: result.phonebook
        });
        // console.log(result);
      });
  };

Comment: Please update your question with relevant, formatted code. Can you post what your state looks like? Also, you are using `.then()` and `async/await`. You should choose one or the other. I would suggest removing your `.then()` block and adding a `console.log(response.data)` after your variable declaration for `response` to see if you are receiving the data correctly.

Comment: I am getting a response back. I can't post all of my code for privacy reasons.

Comment: Let me see if I can post it all and mask the private info

Comment: You don't need to post the response. As long as you can verify that `response.data` is the correct data you need, that's fine. What does your state look like? Does it have a `phonebook` property in it?

Comment: No. There is an initial phonebook state. But I want to update it with the results from the api   class Search extends React.Component {
  state = { companyName: "", firstName: "", lastName: "" };

Comment: If the response you received from your API call is correct, then you should be able to do `this.setState({ phonebooks: response.data.phonebooks })`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209734/discussion-between-khan-and-monique-boea).

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this

```
handleSubmit = event => { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    const response = axios .get( linkhidden.cfc?method=getSearch&companyname=${this.state.companyName}&firstname=${this.state.firstName}&lastname=${this.state.lastName} ) 
        .then(result => { 
            this.setState({ phonebook: result.data.phonebook }); // replaces the current this.state.phonebook
            console.log(result) // displays the result in the screenshot
        }); 
    };
}
```

then you can just display the `this.state.phonebook` in your render (note that since in your screenshot `phonebook` is an array, I'm assuming there are multiple entries)

```
render() {
    return(
        { this.state.phonebook.map((item, index) => (
            <ul key={'phonebook_'+index}>
                { // iterate through each property (or otherwise access them specifically with item.city, item.email_address, etc)
                Object.keys(item).map((itemProperty, itemIndex) => (
                    <li key={'phonebook_'+index+'_'+itemIndex}>
                        {item[itemProperty]}
                    </li>
                ))
            }
            </ul>
        ))}
    )
 }
```

Comment: When I added you code, I get the following

Comment: C:\Users\mboea\Documents\js\phonebook\src\components\Search.js
  84:23  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
  82 |             <ul key={'phonebook_'+index>
  83 |             { // iterate through each property (or otherwise access them specifically with item.city, item.email_address, etc)
> 84 |                 Object.keys(item).map((itemProperty, itemIndex) => (
     |                       ^
  85 |                     <li key={'phonebook_'+index+'_'+itemIndex}>
  86 |                         {item[itemProperty]}
  87 |                     </li>

Comment: forgot some closures, I fixed it in the edit

Comment: Now I get this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I get this with every code snipptet that I try.

Comment: Sounds like `this.state.phonebook` is not initialized properly when the component is mounted. When you declare it in state try `state = { phonebook: [{}] }`. Alternatively you can put a condition and check `this.state.phonebook && this.state.phonebook.length > 0` before calling the map.

Comment: You need to change `this.setState({ phonebook: result.phonebook })` to `this.setState({ phonebook: result.data.phonebook })`. Axios puts the response body on the `data` property. You're most likely getting the error because `response.phonebook` is undefined.

Comment: @bilwit I changed it and got this react_devtools_backend.js:6 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).

Comment: @khan I tried your suggestion and get this map.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: I am getting my response from the API back ok. I just need to know how to iterate over it

Comment: Can you post your `render()` function? You would probably need to initialize `this.state.phonebook` as @bilwit said. In your state, be sure to have `{ phonebook: [] }`. If you have `this.state.phonebook.map(...)` in your render without first initializing it in your state, React will throw an error because `this.state.phonebook` is undefined.

Comment: @khan your suggestion is working. Now, how do I loop over it and display the results?

Comment: @khan I can't post the entire thing. It's too long :(

Comment: This is my iteration  `<tbody>
          {this.phonebook.map((phone, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{phone.lastname}</td>
              <td>{phone.firstname}</td>
              <td>{phone.phone1}</td>
              <td>{phone.phone2}</td>
              <td>{phone.email_address}</td>
              <td>{phone.title}</td>
              <td>{phone.city}</td>
              <td>{phone.state}</td>
              <td>{phone.uregion}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>`

Comment: You need to change `this.phonebook.map()` to `this.state.phonebook.map()`.

Comment: @khan I tried that and get this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209735/discussion-between-khan-and-monique-boea).

Comment: If you initialized the `phonebook` property to an empty array in your state and did `this.state.phonebook.map()` in your `render()` method, then something else is throwing the error. Another possibility is that your `this` context is not referring to your component. It's hard to tell since I don't have the code in front of me. It's important to provide a minimal, reproducible code example that demonstrates your problem. Otherwise, we have these long, extended chat sessions of attempting to debug code.